# workflow inactive - after deployment?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, feature-activation, solution-deployment

my workflow is deployed through the following script in SharePoint 2010:

```
# Set CurrentDirectory
$callingDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $callingDir

# Includes
$MainScriptName = "XXX.SharePoint.Powershell.YYY.ps1"
$MainScriptPath = Join-Path -Path $callingDir -ChildPath $MainScriptName

if (Test-Path $MainScriptPath)
{
    # use file from local folder
    . $MainScriptPath
}
else
{
    # use central file (via PATH-Variable)
    . $MainScriptName
}

Setup

$WebAppUrl = "NONE"

$SolutionPackageName = "Dataport.Survey.Webpart.wsp"
InstallSolution $SolutionPackageName $WebAppUrl

TearDown
```

After that the workflow is shown as "deployed" (solution is provided).
If I want to use the workflow (for example on a list) I can´t do this. In the 
Websitesettings (under "Workflows") the workflow is shown as inactive.
But why? What can I do to use the workflow?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed now. I had accidentally set "hidden=true" on the feature.
If I set "hidden = false" on the feature the Workflow is usable.